# Having trouble correctly testing if right component rendered based on routes passed in as a **component** into App.js using enzyme and jest in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

**Issue:**

I am having trouble testing routes passed in using component. The structure is as follows:  passed into App.js, and then in ClientRoutes I have the various routes. How do I correctly test this?

**Required solution:**

a) I want to test if correct component was rendered based on the route

b) this is optional but also check if correct props passed into the specific component for the specific route

**Structure of my app.test.js**

```js
const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);
const store = mockStore({});
const setup = (props = {}) => {
  return shallow(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  );
};
describe("WelcomeMessage Test Suite", () => {
  it("Should render component", () => {
    let { wrapper } = setup();
    expect(wrapper.length).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

**My app.js render**

```js
 render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.main}>
        <ClientRoutes test="testing" />
      </div>
    );
```

**Finally my clientroutes component**

```js
export default () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
      <Route path={["/login","/"]} exact component={LoginForm} />
      <Route path="*" component={About} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```